# Ubuntu 16.04 errno:28 no space left

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot

I have freshly installed ubuntu 16.04  (alongside Windows 10) and has installed ros, vrep, etc. Now it is showing that there are 0 bytes left even though I have a lot of disk space left (about 500gb). The log file is occupying the whole of the space.

**More info:** `/dev/sda6` is using 402gb and `/dev/sda4` is using 77Gb.
Also during shut down the screen will get stuck, with some code running on the screen for several minutes.

Answer (score 0):

From: "/dev/sda6 is using 402gb and /dev/sda4 is using 77Gb", I am guessing that the root filesystem, / is mounted on /dev/sda6 ? Also that /var/log/* has filled the rest of the partition. You can confirm this with

```
df
```

and

```
du /var/log/* -sh
```

commands? If you don't want to reinstall (on freshly installed) and selecting much less packages to try to minimize on the possibility of installing a faulty package (one which causes the errors) you can first just clear /var/log by removing it all by using sudo rm -rf /var/log/* You want to know what is causing the errors with the installation. Some hardware compatibility or faulty problems? Start of with a miniminal installation and then add to it.